# modify haproxy systemd configuration

Tags: haproxy, systemd

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and I've installed haproxy 1.8.8. I want to modify the config so that the "-f" option will read a directory rather than a single haproxy.cfg file.

I see /lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service and also /etc/init.d/haproxy were installed. I think systemd is managing haproxy. But I've read that I'm not supposed to modify the installed haproxy.service.

I copied haproxy.service to /etc/systemd/system/ and edited it there. The changes I made were not picked up when I ran `sudo systemctl daemon-reload; sudo service haproxy restart`.

Which file do I need to modify and then get systemd to recognize the changes? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, you should not edit the unit-files (provided by the OS packager) directly. You can supply a drop-in-snippet using the command

`systemctl edit haproxy`

and customize the relevant directives (`ExecStart`)